# How to get the variable value from the return of a function in R

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
myFun <- arima(x, order=c(0, 0, 1))
myFun
```

When I run, I got the output:

```
Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(0, 0, 1))

Coefficients:
         ma1  intercept
      0.6023     0.1681
s.e.  0.0827     0.1424

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7958:  log likelihood = -130.7,  aic = 267.39
```

I know that I can get the value of aic by `myFun$aic`, but how can I get the value of:

- Coefficients, ma1, 0.6023
- Coefficients, s.e. , 0.0827
- Coefficients, intercept, 0.1681
- sigman^2 estimated, 0.7958
- etc..

I have searched from the help page, [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.5/topics/Arima), but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Try with `library(broom); tidy(myFun); glance(myFun)`

Comment: If you need it in a single dataset `rowr::cbind.fill(tidy(myFun), glance(myFun))`

Comment: If you need only the coefficient,se, and sigma, this should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get coefficients, you can do `coef(myFun)` or `myFun$coef`

```
myFun$coef
#      ma1 intercept 
#0.9999998 5.4999988
```

Sigma^2 estimated by

```
myFun$sigma2
#[1] 2.750001
```

and standard error by

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(myFun)))
#      ma1 intercept 
#0.3162275 1.0041626
```

and log likelihood

```
myFun$loglik
#[1] -20.44634
```

**data**

```
myFun <- arima(1:10, order=c(0, 0, 1))
myFun

#Call:
#arima(x = 1:10, order = c(0, 0, 1))

#Coefficients:
#         ma1  intercept
#      1.0000     5.5000
#s.e.  0.3162     1.0042

#sigma^2 estimated as 2.75:  log likelihood = -20.45,  aic = 46.89
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use `tidy/glance` from `broom`, which can extract most of the output in a single call

```
library(broom)

rowr::cbind.fill(tidy(myFun), glance(myFun))
#       term    estimate  std.error     sigma    logLik      AIC      BIC
#1       ma1 -0.01357280 0.12869087 0.9847428 -140.3565 286.7129 294.5284
#2 intercept  0.07901125 0.09716588 0.9847428 -140.3565 286.7129 294.5284
```

---

To get the individual components, it is easier to check the structure

```
str(myFun)
```

then we find that it is a named `list`.  So, extract the elements as in extracting any other `list` elements i.e. either with `$` or `[[` for single `list` element (by name or index) and `[` for multiple elements

For more info, we can check this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339953/how-to-extract-standard-error-from-arima-output-in-r) as well

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- rnorm(100)
myFun <- arima(x, order=c(0, 0, 1))
```